# bash: ./configure: Permission denied on NTFS partition

Tags: permissions, configure, ntfs

At first I want to apologize for my poor english.

Is there any way to use bash-scripts like configure on NTFS partitions?

Today I reinstalled my dualboot-system (win7 & mint 13), because my old sys-partitions were to big and I wasted to much space, so I decided today to format disk, with two small sys-partitions and two bigger data partitions. (40G[NTFS] for Win, 40G for Mint (35G[Ext4] + 5G Swap), 2* ~200G[NTFS]). Ok I guess that'S enough for the preface.

So here comes my prob:
So I loaded the wine-git repo and stored it onto one of my data-partitions. So here comes my first prob, couldn't run ./configure because there weren't any execute permissions for that file (I already solved the prob for setting the file permissions, with usermapping to use the ntfs acl). So after setting the execute permissions I'm still not able to run ./configure, I just get the error msg: bash: ./configure: Permission denied  (Just for record, Ya I try to run it as root).

So, does anybody know how I can run a configure script on a NFTS-Partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS doesn't support permissions in the same way as EXT and similar volumes do.  The problem you're running into is that since these permissions are not stored on the disk, defaults are loaded at mount time for the entire volume and changes are silently ignored after that.

You should be able to mount it with execute permissions with the following:

```
mount [devicename] [directory] -o default,remount
```

You will need to be the superuser.  You do NOT include the brackets around the filenames (though they will need to be in quotes if they contain spaces.)

You can figure out what the devicename and directory are by using:

```
mount -l
```

Which will list all mounted devices, and their mount points.  You should not need to be the superuser to issue this command.

Comment: `-o` is the options flag.  `remount` obviously remounts an already mounted filesystem (most often used to change options on a live partition). `default` mounts with the default settings (which include, among other things, `exec`, which will allow you to execute files on the volume).  If that line doesn't work, try `-o default,remount,exec` instead of `-o default,remount`

Comment: What should be the mount command if remounting is not supported (Fedora 17)?

Comment: I'd unmount it first and remove the remount option.

Comment: I used `ntfs-mount` command or something like that after unmounting. It did the trick temporary.

Comment: ⁺¹, I never knew that if the file system doesn't support a permissions then used a rights that was sended to `mount` command. Useful info.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 17 I use following commands to mount NTFS volume with all executable permissions set correctly:

```
sudo mkdir /run/media/ohmyname/shared
sudo ntfsmount /dev/sda8 /run/media/ohmyname/shared
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 26, everything is as simple as it could be.
I mounted Win 10 partition with write permissions using the following command:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda9
```